# VHDX File Empty When Mounted Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-10, backup, mount

I've found a old vhdx backup on a harddrive and I want to get some files off of it.

Whenever I mount the disk is Windows 10, it mounts an empty volume even though the vhdx file is 350gb.

Here is an image of the file on disk (vhdx file).
[image: Image of vhdx file]

And this is what happens when I mount it.

[image]

Why is it mounting an empty volume?

Comment: Can you boot the vhdx image in a VM?

Comment: I would presume the .vhdx is suppose to be empty and I would also presume the reason it still is 350GB is because you have not ran the compacted the file.  At one point I presume it did contain files now it does not.

Comment: When trying to open in VirtualBox I get the following error. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91292881/ShareX/2015/12/VirtualBox_-_Error_2015-12-29_16-48-21.png

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the error in the question itself (including) a link to the url itself to avoid Dropbox permissions problems in the future.